# gfortran compiler error with dynamic (allocatable) vector

Tags: compiler-errors, fortran, dynamic-memory-allocation, gfortran

I am working on a large Fortran code made of multiple modules and using OOP features. I am facing a bug when compiling this code with gfortran versions 7 to 9.

- I am providing below a minimal working example to reproduce the bug. It can be saved as `test.f95` and compiled with `gfortran -fcheck=all -c test.f95`.
- The bug is triggered when `-fcheck=all` is passed to the compiler.
- The bug appears with gfortran 7, 8 and 9, but not with previous versions (tested with gfortran 5 and 6). See compiler outputs below.
- I am using Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS, 4.15.0-65-generic x86_64

Could someone try to reproduce and confirm this bug? I have looked at the different bug tracking systems but could not find anything similar. I have not reported it yet and would like to make sure it is worth reporting before doing so.

Also, is there a way of getting around this compiler error?

---

**Minimal working example:**

```
module buggy
  implicit none

  type :: par
  contains
    procedure, public :: fun => fun_par
  end type par

  type comp
    class(par), allocatable :: p
  end type comp

  type foo
    type(comp), allocatable :: m(:)
  contains
    procedure, public :: init   => init_foo
    procedure, public :: update => update_foo
  end type foo

contains

  function fun_par(this, x) result(y)
    implicit none
    class(par)          :: this
    integer, intent(in) :: x(:)
    integer             :: y(size(x))
  end function fun_par

  subroutine init_foo(this, n)
    implicit none
    class(foo)          :: this
    integer, intent(in) :: n
    integer             :: k
    allocate(this%m(n))
    do k = 1, n
      allocate(par :: this%m(k)%p)
    end do
  end subroutine init_foo

  subroutine update_foo(this, x)
    implicit none
    class(foo)       :: this
    integer, intent(in) :: x(:)
    integer             :: k
    do k = 1, size(this%m)
      write(*,*) this%m(k)%p%fun(x)
    end do
  end subroutine update_foo

end module buggy
```

A few remarks, from trial and error:

- In the definition of `foo`, the same bug is triggered if `m` is specified as a fixed-length vector (e.g., `type(comp) :: m(10)`). The `allocatable` does not seem to be the culprit here.
- Defining `p` in `comp` using `type(par)` instead of `class(par)` does not trigger the bug. But I need `p` to be polymorphic in my code.
- Same bug when `p` is specified to be a pointer instead of an allocatable vector.
- The dimension of the result `y` in `fun_par()` seems to be problematic: when it is a scalar for example (`y` instead of `y(size(x))`), the bug is not triggered.

---

**Compiler error messages**

with gfortran 9.2.1:

```
$ /usr/bin/gfortran-9 -fcheck=all -c test.f95 
test.f95:50:0:

   50 |       write(*,*) this%m(k)%p%fun(x)
      | 
internal compiler error: in gfc_conv_procedure_call, at fortran/trans-expr.c:6785
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-9/README.Bugs> for instructions.
```

with gfortran 8.3.0:

```
$ /usr/bin/gfortran-8 -fcheck=all -c test.f95 
test.f95:50:0:

       write(*,*) this%m(k)%p%fun(x)

internal compiler error: in gfc_conv_procedure_call, at fortran/trans-expr.c:6410
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-8/README.Bugs> for instructions.
```

with gfortran 7.4.0:

```
$ /usr/bin/gfortran-7 -fcheck=all -c test.f95 
test.f95:50:0:

       write(*,*) this%m(k)%p%fun(x)

internal compiler error: in gfc_conv_procedure_call, at fortran/trans-expr.c:6290
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs> for instructions.
```

with gfortran 6.5.0 and gfortran 5.5.0: no error.

Comment: The error message is quite clear *Please submit a full bug report,*. It is even more important, if it is a regression (if it worked before).

Comment: Thanks, I just filed the bug to bugzilla: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=92050.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unknown internal compiler errors are *always* worth reporting.  In this case I also cannot find a report, but someone more familiar with gcc's history may be able to find one.

To work around this compiler error, it seems that you can directly reference the function `fun_par` rather than the binding `fun` of the component `p`:

```
write(*,*) fun_par(this%m(1)%p, x)
```

Finally, we can make the example slightly more minimal:

```
module buggy
  implicit none

  type :: par
  contains
    procedure, public :: fun => fun_par
  end type par

  type comp
    class(par), allocatable :: p
  end type comp

  type foo
    type(comp), allocatable :: m(:)
  end type foo

contains

  function fun_par(this)
    class(par)          :: this
    integer             :: fun_par(1)
    fun_par=0
  end function fun_par

  subroutine update_foo(this)
    class(foo)       :: this
    write(*,*) this%m(1)%p%fun()
  end subroutine update_foo

end module buggy
```